# bash regex to match semantic version number

Tags: regex, bash, semantic-versioning

I have the following:

```
versionNumber=$(sw_vers -productVersion) # Finds version number

versionShort=${versionNumber:0:4}  # Cut string to 1 decimal place for calculation
```

which works when versions are like this:

```
10.9.2
10.9.5
```

but it will not match

```
10.10.3
```

as it will return only

```
10.1
```

but I want the versionShort to be set to

```
10.10
```

I am wanting to match the major version, the first dot and the minor version as above.

Answer (score 16):

Regexp solution:

```
[[ $versionNumber =~ ^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+ ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[0]}"
```

It will always print first two numbers, for example all these:

```
10.5
10.5.9
10.5.8.2
```

Will result in `10.5` output. You can also add an `else` clause to check if something wrong happened (no match found).

Here is a longer version:

```
if [[ $versionNumber =~ ^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+ ]]; then
    versionShort=${BASH_REMATCH[0]}
else
    echo "Something is wrong with your version" >&2
fi
```

Comment: how do i return the result to a variable?

Comment: @lukemh I have added a longer version that might be clearer for you. If it does not work... are you sure that you're using bash? If yes, then which version? In version 3 you have to put right side of the conditional expression into a variable.

Comment: [semantic version](http://semver.org) tags must have exactly 3 numbers.

Comment: @MikeSamuel yes, that's right. Feel free to edit the answer. I wish it was easier to delete it altogether, but mentioning ``BASH_REMATCH`` is a worthy goal, even with a bad answer like this.

Comment: … or write your own, and I'll delete mine :)

Answer (score 15):

Regexpless solution - cut off last dot and whatever follows it:

```
versionShort=${versionNumber%.*}
```

Comment: Careful, this doesn't work when using semver versions with a prerelease suffix like `10.9.5-rc.1`

Answer (score 13):

I had a similar question, but I needed access to all 3 segments. I did a bit of research and testing and I found this to work well

```
product_version=$(sw_vers -productVersion)
semver=( ${product_version//./ } )
major="${semver[0]}"
minor="${semver[1]}"
patch="${semver[2]}"
echo "${major}.${minor}.${patch}"
```

To answer this question directly, you could

```
product_version=$(sw_vers -productVersion)
semver=( ${product_version//./ } )
major="${semver[0]}"
minor="${semver[1]}"
patch="${semver[2]}"
versionShort="${major}.${minor}"
```

or you can use less variables

```
product_version=$(sw_vers -productVersion)
semver=( ${product_version//./ } )
versionShort="${semver[0]}.${semver[1]}"
```

Comment: How does "semver=( ${product_version//./ } )" work? I unfortunately get semver="10.11.6//./"   when I try this.

Comment: @JasonHarrison the code works by replacing dot "." with space " ", and then taking all the arguments as a bash array. In order for it to work you need to assign the semver text to a variable first. For example, `a="10.11.6"; semver=( ${a//./ } )`

Answer (score 9):

https://github.com/fsaintjacques/semver-tool
https://github.com/fsaintjacques/semver-tool/blob/master/src/semver

```html
SEMVER_REGEX="^(0|[1-9][0-9]*)\\.(0|[1-9][0-9]*)\\.(0|[1-9][0-9]*)(\\-[0-9A-Za-z-]+(\\.[0-9A-Za-z-]+)*)?(\\+[0-9A-Za-z-]+(\\.[0-9A-Za-z-]+)*)?$"


function validate-version {
  local version=$1
  if [[ "$version" =~ $SEMVER_REGEX ]]; then
    # if a second argument is passed, store the result in var named by $2
    if [ "$#" -eq "2" ]; then
      local major=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
      local minor=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
      local patch=${BASH_REMATCH[3]}
      local prere=${BASH_REMATCH[4]}
      local build=${BASH_REMATCH[5]}
      eval "$2=(\"$major\" \"$minor\" \"$patch\" \"$prere\" \"$build\")"
    else
      echo "$version"
    fi
  else
    error "version $version does not match the semver scheme 'X.Y.Z(-PRERELEASE)(+BUILD)'. See help for more information."
  fi
}
```

Comment: Note: this snippet contains code that is licensed under GNU GPL v3: https://github.com/fsaintjacques/semver-tool/blob/master/LICENSE