# Split semantic version number using zsh

Tags: macos, zsh, semantic-versioning, macos-catalina

With the release of macOS 10.15 Catalina, the default shell will be switched from `bash` to `zsh`. While reviewing some scripts and documentation, I realized that parameter expansion changes would need to be made.

Following the question [bash regex to match semantic version number](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24318927/2233241), I needed to update my method of collecting semantic version numbers.

In `zsh`, how can I split semantic version numbers using parameter expansion?

Answer (score 1):

[While using my previous answer as a template](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35903168/2233241), I was able to convert my code to [use zsh parameter expansion](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion-Flags).

```sh
product_version=$(sw_vers -productVersion) # 10.14.6
os_vers=( ${(@s:.:)product_version} ) # ( 10 14 6 )
os_vers_major="${os_vers[1]}" # 10
os_vers_minor="${os_vers[2]}" # 14
os_vers_patch="${os_vers[3]}" # 6
os_vers_build=$(sw_vers -buildVersion) #18G87
echo "${os_vers_major}.${os_vers_minor}.${os_vers_patch}+${os_vers_build}" # 10.14.6+18G87
```

[Note that (by default) zsh arrays start at index `1` *not* `0`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#Array-Subscripts)